# Pandas sort dataframe by column with strings and integers

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column containing both integers and strings:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,'c',1,10], 'b':[5,4,0,6]})
>>> df
    a  b
0   2  5
1   c  4
2   1  0
3  10  6
```

I want to sort the dataframe by column a, treating the strings and integers separately, with strings first:

```
>>> df
    a  b
1   c  4
2   1  0
0   2  5
3  10  6
```

...but Python doesn't allow comparing integers to strings.

```
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()
```

If I first convert all the integers to strings, I don't get what I want:

```
>>> df.a = df.a.astype(str)
>>> df.sort(columns='a')
    a  b
0   1  0
3  10  6
2   2  5
1   c  4
```

Does anyone know of a one-line way to tell Pandas that I want it to sort strings first, then integers, without first breaking the dataframe into pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to group the data frame by the data type of column `a` and then sort each group separately:

```
df.groupby(df.a.apply(type) != str).apply(lambda g: g.sort_values('a')).reset_index(drop = True)
```

[image]